# JS Regex - non capture optional quotes

Tags: javascript, regex

Struggling getting a working regex that doesn't capture quotes which are optional.

Code and jsfiddle below.

https://jsfiddle.net/zx7Lurob/1/

```
var txt = `#VER B 2000 20190403 "Text" 20190413`; //without quote 2000
var txt2 = `#VER B "2000" 20190403 "Text" 20190413`; //with qutoe 2000

var myRegexp = /(#VER)\s+"(.+)"|(.+)\s+(.+?)\s+(\d{8})\s+"(.+)"/g;

do {
    var match = myRegexp.exec(txt2);
    if (match != null)
    {
        match.forEach(function(value) {
        console.log(value);
    });
    //console.log(match);
  }
} while (match != null);
```

Gives a result with quoted values for txt2.

Comment: What are your expected result for your inputs?

Comment: I think you want ``var myRegexp = /(#VER.*?)\s+(?:"([^"]*)"|(\S+))\s+(\d{8})\s+"([^"]*)"/g;``. Then, as the second value in the output, you need to get Group 3 or Group 2, if Group 3 does not match.

Comment: Does [this code](https://jsfiddle.net/wiktor_stribizew/o329xjmz/1/) work as expected?

Comment: Hao, well trying to achieve a regex that handles each segment no matter if the segment has quotes surrounding it but excludes the quotes from the match.

Comment: Wiktor, thanks for you suggestion, tried it in jsfiddle but code does not execute, will look more at you suggestion.

Comment: What do you mean by "does not execute"? Can't you see the `["#VER B","2000","20190403","Text"]` result?

Comment: Wiktor, got the result now. My bad. Seems to work fine, thanks! Tried to streamline the regex for wider usage. See new example below, I however try to handle to the result of the regex but not sure how to access the matching groups. See console log of match: https://jsfiddle.net/cgdobwe3/2/

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```js
var myRegexp = /(#VER.*?)\s+(?:"([^"]*)"|(\S+))\s+(\d{8})\s+"([^"]*)"/g;
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/czw8vp/1). *Details*:

- `(#VER.*?)` - Group 1: `#VER` and then any zero or more chars, other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `(?:"([^"]*)"|(\S+))` - either `"`, then any zero or more chars other than `"` (captured into Group 2), or one or more non-whitespace chars (captured into Group 3),
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `(\d{8})` - Group 4: eight digits
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `"([^"]*)"` - `"`, then any zero or more chars other than `"` (captured into Group 5), and then a `"` char.

See the JavaScript demo:

```js
var txt = `#VER B 2000 20190403 "Text" 20190413`;
var txt2 = `#VER B "2000" 20190403 "Text" 20190413`;

var myRegexp = /(#VER.*?)\s+(?:"([^"]*)"|(\S+))\s+(\d{8})\s+"([^"]*)"/g;

for (var txt of [txt, txt2]) {
  do {
    var match = myRegexp.exec(txt);
    if (match != null)
    {
        console.log(txt, '=>',
             [match[1], match[3] || match[2], match[4], match[5]]);
    }
  } while (match != null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its difficult to determine if a positional way points are intended or
a field delimiter.
Its my guess its actually a hybrid of both.

In that case a simple matching an optional quote on both sides of a
*field* and outside of the capture should do the trick.

```
/(\#VER.*)[ \t]+"?(.+?)"?[ \t]+(\d{8})[ \t]+"(.+)"/
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lj4rzo2s/

```
 ( \#VER .* )                  # (1)
 [ \t]+ 
 
 "?
 ( .+? )                       # (2)
 "?
 [ \t]+ 
 
 ( \d{8} )                     # (3)
 [ \t]+ 
 
 "
 ( .+ )                        # (4)
 "
```